# What actually is $RPM_BUILD_ROOT?

Tags: linux, packaging, rpm

In the process of building an RPM package, I have to specify the BuildRoot and later will be used in %install which invovles $RPM_BUILD_ROOT. I always think that $RPM_BUILD_ROOT is the fake installation for RPM to perform packaging. Then, at install time using the RPM package, it will install into actual location. For example:

```
$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr/bin
```

I thought that $RPM_BUILD_ROOT is for the packaging process only, and in some ways RPM can distinguish the $RPM_BUILD_ROOT and the actual install location when the user performs "rpm -ivh package.rpm" will be /usr/bin.

But recently upon reading some documents, it is suggested that $RPM_BUILD_ROOT is the actual location which will be installed, and the $RPM_BUILD_ROOT is specified by user with the setting of environment variable $RPM_BUILD_ROOT in order to let the users install the package in their desire locations. Otherwise, $RPM_BUILD_ROOT will be null and it will install into the default location. In the above case, it is /usr/bin . Thus, $RPM_BUILD_ROOT is not just for packaging or "fake installation" process, but is a way for user to define install location, similar to select folder location in Windows.

I don't know my thinking is correct or not. Can someone please verify? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` (or the equivalent `%{buildroot}` SPEC file macro) *always* holds the directory under which RPM will look for any files to package. The RPM scripts (e.g. the script that compresses the manual pages) will also use that value to know where to look for the files that were just installed. Normally, this value will be non-empty and contain a location away from the system directories - usually somewhere under `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`.

The author of the SPEC file is expected to make sure that `make install` (or whatever installer the software in question is using) will place any files under `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`, with the same hierarchy that should be used when the software is finally installed. E.g. to have RPM install `ls` in `/bin/ls`, the `%install` SPEC file section should make sure that `ls` is placed in `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/bin/ls`.

The author of the SPEC file is also expected to use the `BuildRoot:` tag to specify a proper location. Alternatively, the build system could have an `rpmrc` RPM configuration file with a proper entry. In [any case](http://rpm5.org/docs/api/buildroot.html) the build root should be set, so that:

- Normal users will be able to build the source package.
- Should the superuser ever build the source package, the build process will not clobber any system files, unless the superuser installs the resulting binary package. And yes, there may be a good reason to build *some* packages as `root` - for example, running the full `glibc` testsuite requires `root` privileges for some tests.

That said, RPM can and will build a package with an empty build root variable. In that case both the build install and the final destination locations will coincide. A potential call to e.g. `make install` will use the default locations, thus clobbering the system files under e.g. `/usr/lib` if run with sufficient privileges. Additionally, having `/usr/bin/*` in your `%files` section will happily pull the whole contents of the build host `/usr/bin/` directory into your binary package.

Bottom line:

- Never use an empty build root.
- Do not build packages as `root` unless there is absolutely no other way.

Comment: So, in the end, $RPM_BUILD_RooT is just a value used for the building process and for the RPM to fake install the files to the build root, so it can get the directory structure for the final install locations. I think my initial understanding about the build root  is correct.

Comment: How do we pass a custom root dir to `make install`?

Comment: Recommend unique $RPM_BUILD_ROOT to support parallel builds on same host by using something like this:
`BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-buildroot-%{version}-%{release}`

Answer (score 18):

the file **~/.rpmmacros** defines the paths per user:

```
%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild
%_tmppath %{_topdir}/tmp
```

and one can also define them with rpmbuild command line parameters:

```
rpmbuild --define '_topdir /home/username/rpmbuild'
```