# Does installing a src.rpm run %install?

Tags: php, linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have source code in source.tar that is in `myrpm-1.0.e17.centos.src.rpm`. When I install the rpm on my machine.

```
rpm -ivh myrpm-1.0.e17.centos.src.rpm
```

I get the SOURCE and SPECS file within the root directory I want.  I now want the RPM to go into that SOURCE folder unpack the tar file (source.tar) and move it to a different location on my machine. I've tried putting this into the `%install` and `%post`. It seems like they are not running, I cannot even make a dir in the install section.

```
%install 

echo "INSTALLING"

mkdir temp/myfile

tar -xvf source.tar
```

When installed there is no message, no temp file made and the tar is not unpacked.  (Same when placed into the `%post`).

Answer (score 1):

No, the handling of source RPM contents is hard-coded. `%pre`, `%post`, `%install` etc. are only used when actually *building* the binary package.

In general, you should not do things like this anyway. If you need to unpack the source file or apply patches, just do it in the `%pre` section, which is executed as part of the binary package build process before the actual build starts. That ensures that the build is at least somewhat repeatable.

We might be able to help more if you mentioned [what is the problem that you are trying to solve by doing this](http://xyproblem.info/)...

---

Let's clarify something here. The "S" in SRPM refers to the fact the the SRPM is the *source* from which an installable RPM package is built and that's all. It does *not* mean either that programs in non-compiled packages are installed from SRPMs, or that RPMs only contain binary files. For example:

- When source code for an application is not available, sometimes distributions will include binary executables in their SRPMS, or have them downloaded in their `%build` section.
- Python, Bash and PHP scripts are often included as-is in the resulting RPM. It's not unusual in these cases for `%build` to be completely empty, and for `%install` to just copy the files to their right place under [`$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086283/507519). If the resulting package has no platform-dependent files, then it's usually built as a `.noarch` RPM, but it's still considered a binary RPM and it is *not* an SRPM.

Please, pretty please, don't abuse SRPMs for things that they are not meant for.

Comment: Thank you it does answer my question.  In short I want the source code to be on the server. It is not the duty of the RPM to put the code in the correct location.

Comment: @Eddie: It seems like you are confusing RPM source packages and binary packages. To put files on your server you need to `rpmbuild` your .src.rpm to get a binary .rpm, that you can then install...

Comment: I don't want to get binary's (I'm building this for a php application).  So I have my PHP code packaged up and want to install them via an RPM. I still want to move these files from the tarball and move them to where I would like.

Comment: @Eddie: SRPMs are *not* installable to the system - only to the RPM build environment for use by `rpmbuild`. Period. You need to build binary RPMs to install - if those are architecture independent (e.g. PHP file packages) then they would be .noarch RPMs, but they still would not be SRPMs.